# model averaged coefficients of linear mixed models in glmulti? Fix no longer works

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, glmulti

I'm using the `glmulti` package to do variable selection on the fixed effects of a mixed model in `lme4`. I had the same problem retrieving coefficients and confidence intervals that was solved by the author of the package in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20429678/3349115). Namely using the `coef` or `coef.multi` gives an `check.names` error and the coefficients are listed as `NULL` when calling the `predict` method. So I tried the solution listed on the thread linked above, using:

```
setMethod('getfit', 'merMod', function(object, ...) {
summ=summary(object)$coef
summ1=summ[,1:2]
if (length(dimnames(summ)[[1]])==1) {
    summ1=matrix(summ1, nr=1, dimnames=list(c("(Intercept)"),c("Estimate","Std.    Error")))
}
cbind(summ1, df=rep(10000,length(fixef(object))))
})
```

I fixed the missed `"` in the original post and the code ran. But, now instead of getting

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :arguments imply
>   differing number of rows: 1, 0

I get this error for every single model...

> Error in calculation of the Satterthwaite's approximation. The output
>   of lme4 package is returned summary from lme4 is returned some
>   computational error has occurred in lmerTest

I'm using `lmerTest` and it doesn't surprise me that it would fail if `glmulti` can't pull the correct info from the model. So really it's the first two lines of the error that are probably what should be focussed on.

A description of the original fix is on the developers website [here](https://vcalcagnoresearch.wordpress.com/package-glmulti/). Clearly the package hasn't been updated in awhile, and yes I should probably learn a new package...but until then I'm hoping for a fix. I'll contact the developer directly through his website. But, in the mean time, has anyone tried this and found a fix?

`lme4` `glmulti` `rJava` and other related packages have all been updated to the latest version.

Comment: I don't see any glmulti functions in your code.

Comment: Please see the thread I linked to in the first paragraph. Calling the `coef(object, ...)` function, the `coef.glmulti(object, ...)` or the predict(object, ...)` methods all result in errors as described regardless of the `glmulti` object used. There is a reproducible example in that thread which results in the same errors.

Comment: the `setMethod` code changes the way the `getfit` function pulls out the relevant pieces of the model objects from within the `glmulti` object. This functionality is described in the `glmulti` manual [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/glmulti.pdf), starting on page 7, page 4 for the `coef.glmulti()` function that includes the `coef` and `predict` calls and how they should work.