# glmulti syntax for mixed effects logistic regression in lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, glmulti

I am trying to compare the AIC (or AICc) values of various mixed effects logistic (or for some outcomes gamma) models containing all the variables in my dataset, a simplified version of which can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YO17J7Dx1cFD0Wf3fNGe-a37ccTKyWNp/view?usp=sharing. However I am new to glmulti and have only used lme4 for a month or so, so I believe I am doing something very wrong:

I have set up the initial model containing all variables as follows:

```
data_reprex <- read_csv("reprex_glmulti_data.csv")


data_reprex <- within(data_reprex, {
  Dog <- factor(Dog) 
  Box <-factor(Box)
  Sex <- factor(Sex)
  Group <- factor(Group)
  Breedtype <- factor(Breedtype)
  OwnerSeverity <- factor(OwnerSeverity, levels = c("None", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"))
})


outcome_model <- glmer(SuccessBinary ~ Interval + Box + Trial + Age + Sex + Breedtype + OwnerSeverity +
                         Group + Group*Interval + Group*Box + Group*Trial + Group*Age + Group*Sex + Group*Breedtype 
                       + (1 | Dog), data = data_reprex, family = binomial, nAGQ=100)
```

The model runs fine (with the exception of a few warnings that I have investigated already). However I want to run glmulti for models with each combination of those variables to identify the best model, and have tried several different forms of syntax based on various examples I have found online, but none of these work (I have also tried changing the criterion and "confsetsize" settings):

```
attempt1 <- glmulti(SuccessBinary ~ Interval + Box + Trial + Age + Sex + Breedtype + OwnerSeverity +
         Group + (1 | Dog), data=data_reprex,
       level=1, fitfunction=glmer, family= binomial, crit="aicc", confsetsize=150)

attempt2 <- glmulti(SuccessBinary ~ Interval + Box + Trial + Age + Sex + Breedtype + OwnerSeverity +
                      Group + (1 | Dog), data=data_reprex,
                    level=1, fitfunction=glmer, crit="aicc", confsetsize=150)


attempt3 <- glmulti(outcome_model, level=2, fitfunction=glmer, crit=AICc)

attempt4 <- glmulti(outcome_model, level=2, crit=AICc)
```

The error messages include:

```
Improper call of glmulti.

Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

I also sometimes get warning messages such as:

```
 In Ops.factor(Interval + Box + Trial + Age + Sex + Breedtype + OwnerSeverity,  :
  ‘+’ not meaningful for factors

In Ops.factor(Interval + Box + Trial + Age + Sex + Breedtype + OwnerSeverity +  : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors
```

I am assuming this is a syntax issue and I need to alter the structure of the code because I am using a logistic glmer rather than a glm like most of the examples I have found online, and from the documentation I believe that glmulti should be compatible with models from lme4. Please could someone advise me on how to structure this so that it runs? (Also, is there a relatively straightforward way to include only the interactions with variable "Group" instead of with all of the other variables?)

EDIT: As a last-ditch attempt I have also tried using the advice provided here (though I think I may have got confused somewhat): [glmulti and liner mixed models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429678/glmulti-and-liner-mixed-models) to use the following code, but this does not work either:

```
glmer2.glmulti <- setMethod('getfit', 'merMod', function(object, ...) {
  summ=summary(object)$coef
  summ1=summ[,1:2]
  if (length(dimnames(summ)[[1]])==1) {
    summ1=matrix(summ1, nr=1, dimnames=list(c("(Intercept)"),c("Estimate","Std. Error")))
  }
  cbind(summ1, df=rep(10000,length(fixef(object))))
})

attempt5 <- glmulti(SuccessBinary ~ Interval + Box + Trial + Age + Sex + Breedtype + OwnerSeverity +
                      Group + (1 | Dog), data=data_reprex,
                    level=1, fitfunction=glmer2.glmulti, family=binomial, crit="aicc", confsetsize=150)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Sorry no, just submitted my thesis and I mentioned the package as a potential way of comparing AICs but said that all attempts to use it for this type of model failed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and congrats on finishing!! I posted my own question and was told glmulti is just too outdated, was encouraged to just find another approach

Answer (score 1):

I got confused myself and also tried to apply glmulti to a mixed effect model fitted with glmmTMB and got very similar error messages than you did. I did not manage to make it work with glmulti, but it seems that the function dredge from MuMIn package [here](https://github.com/cran/MuMIn/blob/master/R/pdredge.R) is working for me. Maybe you could try this? (In case you haven't found a solution yet).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and found [the solution here.](https://yuzar-blog.netlify.app/posts/2022-05-31-glmulti/#some-exotic-applications-glmer-or-multinom)

Note that the `glmer.glmulti` wrapper function contains the deprecated `REML` argument.

EDIT: The asker was asking for the syntax for `lme4::glmer` that would work with `glmulti`. I'm writing down what has worked for me here, so that moderators might approve the answer. But essentially I'm just copy-pasting what is on the cited source.

```
# wrapper function for argument fitfunction in glmulti()
glmer.glmulti <- function(formula, data, random = "", ...){
  glmer(paste(deparse(formula),random),
        data    = data, 
        # REML = F, # argument deprecated in newer version of lme4
        ...)
}

res1 <- glmulti(
  y = outcome_variable ~ predictor1 + predictor2,
  random  = "+(1|cluster_variable)",
  crit    = aicc,
  data    = data,
  family  = binomial,
  method  = "h",
  fitfunction = glmer.glmulti,
  marginality = F,
  level   = 1)
```